# How to format numbers in ejs templates?

Tags: javascript, ejs, number-formatting

I'd like to format floating numbers in ejs, printf-like, like this:
`printf("%2.2f", mynumber)`

Is there a recommended compact way to do this?

Comment: How about toFixed() or toPrecision() methods?

Answer (score 1):

There is no printf-like function that I'm aware of, but you do have access to javascript functions, so you can take advantage of toFixed() and padStart() to do something like this:

```
<%= mynumber.toFixed(2).padStart(5,'0') %>
```

You'll notice I used a 5 in padStart() to accommodate for the decimal point and I wouldn't expect this to work well with negative numbers. If you need support for negative numbers you'll have to add in a conditional and it will get much messier. It might look something like this:

```
<% 
  if ( mynumber >= 0 ) { 
    %><%= mynumber.toFixed(2).padStart(5,'0') %><%
  } else {
    %><%= "-" + (-1 * mynumber).toFixed(2).padStart(5,'0') %><%
  }
%>
```

You could try shrinking it down:

```
<%= (mynumber >= 0)
      ? mynumber.toFixed(2).padStart(5,'0')
      : "-" + (-1 * mynumber ).toFixed(2).padStart(5,'0') %>
```

But either way it's pretty ugly.